# Passenger: The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Connection closed

Tags: ruby, passenger, redmine

I was trying to deploy Redmine to Apache with mod_passenger on CentOS 6.3 but having the error :

> The application spawner server exited unexpectedly: Connection closed

I installed the latest version (3.0.18) of passenger using gem.

After various failed attempts I decided to delete passenger from "gem uninstall passenger" and install it again using "yum install rubygem-passenger" instead. The installed version was "3.0.17"

Then it started working. Still don't know why exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I also had same issue and figured out.

You may have `RailsBaseURI` directives in your apache config file. If you're using Rails 3, it should be changed to `RackBaseURI`.

See these

- [Passenger error - PhusionPassenger::ClassicRails::ApplicationSpawner::Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430847/passenger-error-phusionpassengerclassicrailsapplicationspawnererror)
- http://wiki.railsplayground.com/railsplayground/show/How+To+use+Phusion+Passenger
- http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Answer (score 0):

What other errors do you see in the log file?

Can you also try Phusion Passenger 4 beta from github's master branch?